# How do I fetch the HTML source of a URL in Android?

Tags: android, html, kotlin, url

In my Kotlin Android application I want to do the following:

1. Get the HTML source of a URL
2. Get the URL from the first `img` tag inside the HTML source that was retrieved

How should I go about doing this? Is there a library available for Android where you can send a URL and get the HTML source in return?

Comment: What is "metadata" in this context? You can get the HTML by just loading the Web page using an HTTP client API, such as OkHttp.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, that wasn't clear. I revised the question as I believe I only need the HTML source code of a webpage. To answer your other question, I'm not trying to load the website on the user's end. I want to just get the HTML source code of a website without having to show the actual site or load it to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get the HTML source of a URL

Use any HTTP client API. I recommend OkHttp, but there are plenty of others.

> Get the URL from the first img tag inside the HTML source that was retrieved

Parse the HTML using an HTML parser, and use the parsed result to find your desired HTML tag. [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) is fairly popular, and it also happens to include an HTTP client, which you might use instead of OkHttp or anything else.

You would wind up with something like:

```kotlin
val doc = Jsoup.connect("YOUR URL GOES HERE").get()
val firstImg = doc.select("img").first()
```

Comment: The `val doc` line is giving me an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` error. I already have OkHttp in my `build.gradle`, but I'm not sure how that's supposed to be used in this context.

Comment: @TomDarious: You need to do that work in a background thread of some form. For example, your viewmodel or repository could do this work using Kotlin coroutines.

Comment: Instead of simply getting the first `img` tag, is there a way to get the first `img` tag that meets certain requirements? For example, a `img` tag that has an `alt` attribute and a full `http` or `https` url that includes either a `.jpg`, `.jpeg` or `.png` image format?

Comment: @TomDarious: See [the JSoup documentation](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for the selector syntax that I used in the `select()` call.